# Stage navigation multiple robots

Tags: navigation, rviz, stageros, scan, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I want to have multiple robots in stage navigation.
I used the stage navigation tutorial code.
The problem is I can have gmapping with 1 robot.
But if I include a second robot the TF doesnt work and gmapping does not work any more.

My laser.world file:

> define obstacle model (   size [0.5
> 0.5 0.5]   gui_nose 0   obstacle_return 1 )
>
> define hokuyo ranger (   sensor(
> range [ 0.02  4.0 ]
> fov 180
> samples 682   )   block(
> points 4
> point[0] [0 1]
> point[1] [1 1]
> point[2] [1 0]
> point[3] [0 0]
> z [0 1]   )     color "black"   size [ 0.05 0.05 0.1 ] )
>
> define roomba position (   block   (
> points 4        point[0]  [ 0.700 0.705 ]
> point[1]  [ 0.700 0.0 ]         point[2]
> [ 0.0 0.0 ]       point[3]  [ 0.0 0.705 ]
> z [0 1]   )     size [0.7 0.705 0.3]
> origin [-0.125 0 0 0]   color
> "gray50"
>
> gui_nose 1   obstacle_return 1
>
> drive "diff"
>
> localization "gps" )
>
> define roomba_hokuyo roomba(      color
> "gray90"  hokuyo(pose [ 0.1 0.0 0.0
> 0.0 ]) )
>
> define turtlebot roomba(      color
> "gray90"  origin [-0.100 0 0 0] )
>
> define floorplan model (   color
> "gray30"   boundary 1
>
> gui_nose 0   gui_grid 0
> gui_outline 0   gui_move 0
> gripper_return 0   fiducial_return 0
> obstacle_return 1    ranger_return 0.8
> )
>
> define zone model (   color   "orange"
> size [ 4 4 0.01 ]
>
> gui_nose 0   gui_grid 0   gui_move 1
> gui_outline 0
>
> obstacle_return 0   ranger_return -1
> )
>
> window (  size [ 500.000 400.000 ]
> scale 20            center [ 0.0  0.0
> ]     rotate [ 0  0 ]
> show_data 1    show_trailarrows 0 ) floorplan (
> name "map"   size [20.000 15.000
> 0.800]   pose [0 1 0 0]   bitmap "map.png" )
>
> roomba_hokuyo (
> name "roomba_hokuyo_0"   pose [ 0.00
> 0.00 0 0.00 ] )
>
> roomba_hokuyo (
> name "roomba_hokuyo_1"   pose [ 1.00
> 0.00 0 0.00 ] )

Laser_gmapping.launch:

```
<launch>

  <!-- Launch stage world -->
    <param name="/use_sim_time" value="true"/>
  <include file="$(find stage_worlds)/launch/laser_world.launch" />

  <!-- Launch robot model -->
  <param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro.py '$(find stage_navigation)/urdf/robot.urdf.xacro'" />

  <!-- Run gmapping -->
  <include file="$(find stage_navigation)/move_base_config/slam_gmapping.xml"/>

  <!-- Run Move Base  -->
  <include file="$(find stage_navigation)/move_base_config/move_base.xml"/>

  <group ns="robot1">
    <param name="tf_prefix" value="robot1_tf" />
    <param name="amcl/initial_pose_x" value="1" />
    <param name="amcl/initial_pose_y" value="1" />
  </group>

  <group ns="robot2">
    <param name="tf_prefix" value="robot2_tf" />
    <param name="amcl/initial_pose_x" value="-1" />
    <param name="amcl/initial_pose_y" value="1" />
  </group>

  <!-- Run rviz -->
  <include file="$(find stage_navigation)/launch/navigation_rviz.launch" />


</launch>
```

Tell me if you need more files.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/221271/stage-navigation-multiple-robots/) by [gijsje170](https://answers.ros.org/users/25135/gijsje170/) on ROS Answers with karma: 171 on 2015-11-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The question is similar to [this one](http://answers.ros.org/question/227728/multiple-robots-simulation-in-stage-with-amcl-navigation/). I got the answer to it and it is summarized in this [github repository](https://github.com/gergia/multiple_turtlebots_stage_amcl)

---

Originally posted by [gavran](https://answers.ros.org/users/26097/gavran/) with karma: 526 on 2016-05-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0